# Android keyguard manager

Tags: android

fellows i found a code but i can't found out what are the last two imports, where to find them

http://hi-android.info/src/android/app/KeyguardManager.java.html

Answer (score 0):

They are defined in .aidl files. i found them [here](http://code.taobao.org/trac/cnAndroidSDK/browser/trunk/dev/src/android/view/IWindowManager.aidl?rev=201). Can pull from the google source too.

Comment: can somebody upload implementation cause i can't figure out how to do it i tried several times

Comment: you asked where to find the files I gave the link to location. The question has been answered.